# How to move an entire row up/down in R based on condition?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Say I have some data that looks like this

```
Name     Type   Rating

Dave     Good   3.0
Steve    Bad    0.0
Steve    Good   2.0
Dave     Bad    1.0
Tom      Bad    2.0
Marianne Good   0.0
Tom      Bad    1.0
Steve    Bad    5.5
Marianne Bad    3.0
```

And I want to take any row that meets the conditions 'type=='good'' and 'Rating==2.0' and move that entire row up or down 1 row. How would I go about doing that in R?

So it would look like this.

```
Name     Type   Rating

Dave     Good   3.0
Steve    Good   2.0
Steve    Bad    0.0
Dave     Bad    1.0
Tom      Bad    2.0
Marianne Good   0.0
Tom      Bad    1.0
Steve    Bad    5.5
Marianne Bad    3.0
```

Comment: Unclear to me what do you mean by move up or down one space. Please show your desired output.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Used the word 'space' instead of 'row' for some reason. Updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this get you what you want? I used a slightly edited `data.frame` to show how this deals with edge cases (i.e. you want to move down, but you are already at the last row).

```
rows <- rep(which(df$Type == "Good" & df$Rating == 2.0), each = 2)
all_rows <- 1:nrow(df)
#For moving DOWN change "-" to "+"
all_rows[replace(rows - c(1,0), rows - c(1,0) > nrow(df) | rows - c(1,0) < 1, NA) %>% na.omit] <- replace(rows - c(0,1), rows - c(0,1) > nrow(df) | rows - c(0,1) < 1, NA) %>% na.omit
df[all_rows,]



#          Name Type Rating
#1      Mike Good    2.0
#2      Dave Good    3.0
#4     Steve Good    2.0
#3     Steve  Bad    0.0
#5      Dave  Bad    1.0
#6       Tom  Bad    2.0
#7  Marianne Good    0.0
#8       Tom  Bad    1.0
#9     Steve  Bad    5.5
#11    Steve Good    2.0
#10 Marianne  Bad    3.0
```

---

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text="Name     Type   Rating
Mike     Good   2.0
Dave     Good   3.0
Steve    Bad    0.0
Steve    Good   2.0
Dave     Bad    1.0
Tom      Bad    2.0
Marianne Good   0.0
Tom      Bad    1.0
Steve    Bad    5.5
Marianne Bad    3.0
Steve    Good   2.0", header = T)
```

Comment: That does exactly what I want. Thank you very much!

Comment: Very intelligent answer to arrive a solution in base-R. I was just wondering if it would be  efficient to write a function to swap rows.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution can be achieved using `ifelse` and `which`. I have used `data.frame` from `@MikeH` answer to include end conditions.

```
matched <- which(df$Type == "Good" & df$Rating == 2.0 )
all <- 1:nrow(df)

#move up by 1
swapped_row <- ifelse(all %in% (matched-1), all+1, 
                      ifelse(all %in% matched & all != 1, all-1, all))

df[swapped_row,]
#       Name Type Rating
#1      Mike Good    2.0
#2      Dave Good    3.0
#4     Steve Good    2.0
#3     Steve  Bad    0.0
#5      Dave  Bad    1.0
#6       Tom  Bad    2.0
#7  Marianne Good    0.0
#8       Tom  Bad    1.0
#9     Steve  Bad    5.5
#11    Steve Good    2.0
#10 Marianne  Bad    3.0

# A bit generic way to cover 1+ row shift up
n = 1 # 1 to move up by 1
swapped_row <- ifelse(all %in% (matched-n), all+n, 
                      ifelse(all %in% matched & all>n , all-n, all))

# A bit generic way to cover 1+ row shiftdown
n = -1 # -1 to move down by 1
swapped_row <- ifelse(all %in% (matched-n), all+n, 
       ifelse(all %in% matched & all<(n+length(all)) , all-n, all))
```

## Data

```
df <- read.table(text="Name     Type   Rating
Mike     Good   2.0
                 Dave     Good   3.0
                 Steve    Bad    0.0
                 Steve    Good   2.0
                 Dave     Bad    1.0
                 Tom      Bad    2.0
                 Marianne Good   0.0
                 Tom      Bad    1.0
                 Steve    Bad    5.5
                 Marianne Bad    3.0
                 Steve    Good   2.0", header = T)
```